# Best way to initialize key/value pairs in dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working in Python 3

I have a board with cells that I have to store, each cell has a coordinate and needs to store 3 values. I used a dictionary where the key equals the coordinates of the cell and the value is a list of 3 elements that stores the required values. 
Will it be fast to get and read these values  when the board gets big and a lot of key/value pairs are stored? 
Or what other method would be more efficient in terms of speed?

Alex

EDIT:

The 3 values that I need for each cell are zero's or ones. I have a tuple that contains the dimension of the board, a tuple that contains all the cell positions that should have a value of 1 as a first value, a frozenset that contains all the cell positions that should have a value of 1 as a second value and a tuple that contains all the cell positions that should have a value of 1 as a 3rd value:

tuple1 is a tuple that contains tuples that each represent the positions of the cells that have a 1 as first value, frozenset contains tuples that each represent the positions of the cells that have a 1 as second value, and tuple2 contains tuples that each represent the positions of the cells that have 1 as a third value (in the list)

Code:

```
board = {}

for row in range(dimension[0]):
    for col in range(dimension[1]):
        board[(row,col)] = [0,0,0] #default
for x in tuple1:
    board[x][0] = 1

for x in frozenset:
    board[x][1] = 1

for x in tuple2:
    board[x][2] = 1

return board
```

Will it now be fast to look up keys and there values?

EDIT2: is this the fastest method to set up a dictionary like this?

Comment: Show the code (a small example)

Comment: do you mean you will be doing something like `board[(x,y,z)] = [a,b,c]` ?

Comment: I edited the post with the code, I am indeed doing something like that!

Comment: It depends on the scope and purpose of the application, for example, if it gets huge you'll want to look into persistent storage using databases. For a small application your method is probably fine, but like I say - it depends.

Comment: It's relatively small, there will be max 2400 key/value pairs in the dict

Comment: [so] has edit history. Using *EDIT* in a post instead of rewriting the post gives the impression you don't care about people having to read your post. Please rewrite your post as a single coherent whole that can be understood without referring to comments that might have been made after the initial posting (and that can be deleted at will).

Answer (score 2):

## With `numpy`

If you're looking for performance, I think you should seriously consider [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)  with boolean values. Your 2-D Board with tuples as values could be seen as a 3D Matrix:

```
import numpy as np

width, height = 5, 5

board = np.full((width,height,3), False, dtype = bool)
tuple1 = ((1,2), (3,4), (0,2))

for i,j in tuple1:
    board[i,j,0] = True

print(board)
#   [[[False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [ True False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]]

#    [[False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [ True False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]]

#    [[False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]]

#    [[False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [ True False False]]

#    [[False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]
#     [False False False]]]
```

## With standard lists

If you cannot use `numpy`, you could simply use standard lists:

```
width, height = 5, 5

board = [[[0, 0, 0] for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]
tuple1 = ((1,2), (3,4), (0,2))

for i,j in tuple1:
    board[i][j][0] = 1

from pprint import pprint
pprint(board)  
[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

I don't think there's any advantage in using a dict. It would just shuffle your cells and make display harder.

Comment: Using external modules is a no-go in my case, I can only use Python's built in modules

Comment: @AlexanderAmeye: Too bad, `numpy` seems like a good fit. Note that it is often included in Python standard distributions.

Comment: @AlexanderAmeye: Updated example with lists. It should be easier than with a dict

Comment: So using lists won't slow the whole thing down? I thought the advantage of using dicts was the speed of looking up keys and getting their values?

Comment: Because I'll need to edit values of those lists a lot, and I want that to happen very quickly :)

Comment: @AlexanderAmeye: Yes, if the key is `"a_string"` or `some_other_object`. Here your "keys" are integers, and they are the cell coordinates : you know them, so you can access them directly with `board[i][j][k]`.